# ion-input shape property bug?

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic5

[image]I am trying to create a form with rounded inputs. Using the docs [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input) I am putting the "shape" and "fill" on ion-input vs the now-deprecated usage on ion-item. However, ion-input seemingly wants to square off the left side? No amount of margin or padding seems to update it. Is it a bug in ionic or am I doing something wrong?

```
           <ion-item shape="round" fill="outline" lines="none">
             <ion-input v-model="name" name="name" type="text" :spellcheck="false" autocapitalize="off"
                   :placeholder="namePlaceholder" required></ion-input>
          </ion-item>

          <ion-item lines="none">
             <ion-input v-model="email" shape="round" fill="outline" name="email" type="email" :spellcheck="false" 
                   autocapitalize="off" :placeholder="emailPlaceholder" required></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nested your ion-input inside an ion-item. You should remove the encapsulating ion-item and move the styling inside the ion-input.

Comment: no what i am saying is: the docs say NOT to add "rounded" to ion-item, but rather to ion-input. BUT ion-input does not work the same, as evidenced by the 2nd entry (the email input)

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding your question, in that case your problem (from reading the documentation) is that you nested your ion-input inside an ion-item. You should remove the encapsulating ion-item and move the styling inside the ion-input.

Comment: thank you if you want to make that the answer i will accept it